# Цикл не отрабатывает PHP

Tags: php

Подскажите пожалуйста! Есть (ниже код), он должен работать так: если $fileSize (общий вес всех файлов в папке storage) превысил максимальное допустимое значение $maxFileSize, тогда удаляй файлы в папке storage пока $fileSize станет меньше либо равно $maxFileSize.

Сам цикл отрабатывает только один раз, т.е. удаляет один файл, для следующего удаления нужно рефрешить страницу.

```
if($fileSize > $maxFileSize){
    do{
        if (unlink("storage/$oldFile"))
            echo "<span style='text-align: center; color: red;'>Файл: $oldFile - удален!</span>"; 
        else 
            echo "<span style='text-align: center; color: red;'>Папка <b>storage</b> пуста!</span>";

        function getFilesSize(){ // Функция определения размера папки
            $path = 'storage';
            $fileSize = 0;
            $dir = scandir($path); // Получить список файлов и каталогов, расположенных по указанному пути
            foreach($dir as $file){
            if (($file!='.') && ($file!='..'))
                if(is_dir($path . '/' . $file))
                    $fileSize += getFilesSize($path.'/'.$file);
                else
                    $fileSize += filesize($path . '/' . $file);
        }
        return $fileSize; // Возвращает значение "размер файлов в Кбайтах"
        }
        $fileSize = (int)((getFilesSize()/1024)/1024); // Округление до Мбайтов
    } while ($fileSize <= $maxFileSize);
    }
```

Comment: для следующего удаления нужно рефрешить страницу

Возможно к сожалению PHP не работает динамически...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы в цикле объявляете функцию, при следующем шаге цикла выдаётся `Fatal Error: Cannot redeclare getFilesSize` Но эту ошибку вы не видите, потом что не включен

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Поехали дальше.

```
    $fileSize = (int)((getFilesSize()/1024)/1024); // Округление до Мбайтов
} while ($fileSize <= $maxFileSize);
```

А `$maxFileSize` тоже до мегабайт округлен ?

Вот выложил примерный код, который должен быть:

```
function getFilesSize(){ // Функция определения размера папки
    $path = 'storage';
    $fileSize = 0;
    $dir = scandir($path); // Получить список файлов и каталогов, расположенных по указанному пути
    foreach($dir as $file){
    if (($file!='.') && ($file!='..'))
        if(is_dir($path . '/' . $file)) {
            $fileSize += getFilesSize($path.'/'.$file);
        } else {
            $fileSize += filesize($path . '/' . $file);
        }
    return $fileSize; // Возвращает значение "размер файлов в байтах"
}

function clearFiles($path, &$curSize, $limit) {

    $dir = opendir($path);
    while ($e = readdir($dir)) {
        if ($curSize <= $limit) {
            return true;
        }
        if (substr($e, 0, 1) == '.') {
            continue;
        }
        $fullPath = $dir.'/'.$e;
        if (is_dir($fullPath)) {
            clearFiles($fullPath, $curSize, $limit);
        } elseif (is_file($fullPath)) {
            $curSize -= filesize($fullPath);
            if (unlink($fullPath)) {
                echo "<span style='text-align: center; color: green;'>Файл: $fullPath - удален!</span>"; 
            } else {
                echo "<span style='text-align: center; color: red;'>Не могу удалить: $fullPath</span>";
            }
        }

    }
}

//$maxFileSize =  думаю выше он где то определен
$fileSize = getFilesSize();

if($fileSize > $maxFileSize){
    clearFiles('storage', $fileSize, $maxFileSize);
}
```

Comment: >> а что значит & перед именем переменной $curSize ? 

передача по ссылке. Меняя аргумент функции внутри функции он также меняется.

Comment: Чето ничего не работает! Валится на чем-то! На чем понять не могу :(

Answer (score 1):

Лучше вынесите функцию определения размера папки из цикла, так как это во-первых будет удобнее восприниматься, а во-вторых перестанет казаться, что ошибка где-то там.

```
function getFilesSize() // Функция определения размера папки
{ 
            $path = 'storage';
            $fileSize = 0;
            $dir = scandir($path); // Получить список файлов и каталогов, расположенных по указанному пути
            foreach($dir as $file)
            {
            if (($file!='.') && ($file!='..'))
                if(is_dir($path . '/' . $file))
                    $fileSize += getFilesSize($path.'/'.$file);
                else
                    $fileSize += filesize($path . '/' . $file);
            }
        return $fileSize; // Возвращает значение "размер файлов в Кбайтах"
        }

$filesize = getFilesSize();   // возможно, у вас это уже есть.

if($fileSize > $maxFileSize){
    do{
        if (unlink("storage/$oldFile"))
            echo "<span style='text-align: center; color: red;'>Файл: $oldFile - удален!</span>"; 
        else 
            echo "<span style='text-align: center; color: red;'>Папка <b>storage</b> пуста!</span>";

        $fileSize = floor((getFilesSize()/1024)/1024); // Округление до Мбайтов
    } while ($fileSize <= $maxFileSize);
    }
```

Comment: Такое делал уже, я наоборот запихнул в цикл, чтобы он новое значение запихивал в условие.

Comment: А перед условием

    if($fileSize > $maxFileSize)

инициализируются ли переменные 

    $filesize  и  $maxFileSize

?